# fetching data with react hook returns undefined on nested obj properties

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch, react-hooks

Im trying to display data that has been fetched. but i cannot seem to display nested objects properties in react. Any ideas? if i log the data i first get a undefined, then the correct data.
my guess is that i need to wait for the data to be loaded then display it. but it does work for the title that is not in a nested obj.

```
function SingleBeneficiary({ match }) {

  const [data, setData] = useState({ data: []});
  const id = match.params.id

  useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8081/v1/beneficiary/${id}`);
    const jsonData = await response.json()
    setData(jsonData)
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [])

  return (
 {data.title} // works
{data.address.careOf} // dont work
```

The data

```
{ 
  "title":"myTitle",
  "address":{
    "careOf": "my adress"
  }

}
```

Comment: It would be better to use useReducer to manage JavaScript objects or arrays as state, + console the json data before setData, Does it give proper output?

Comment: log the response data, tell us what you get

Comment: log the response and state data what does it give ?

Comment: IF i log the jsonData directly after the fetch it returns the correct data 

Comment: Before setting state blindly when doing async stuff you should realy check if the [component is still mounted](https://github.com/jmlweb/isMounted) the code of useIsMounted is [here](https://github.com/jmlweb/isMounted/blob/master/index.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try like this?
I set initial data to null, and in return I check if it is not null.
If address can be null, additional null check is required.

```
function SingleBeneficiary({ match }) {

  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const id = match.params.id

  useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8081/v1/beneficiary/${id}`);
    const jsonData = await response.json()
    setData(jsonData)
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [])

    return (
      <div>
        {data && (
          <div>
            <p>data.title</p>
            <p>data.address.careOf</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I dont really understand that syntax? The return ({ dont work

Comment: @csk87  this technique is called Inline If with Logical && Operator.
You can read more about this in reactjs docs.
https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

Answer (score 2):

You should check if `address` has `careOf` property before using it because first time `data` will be undefined and in second render it will have the data after the api call.

```
{data.address && data.address.careOf}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is having a similar issue(i.e. fetching data via api and only the first time it runs, it will show the data as undefined but after manual refreshing, it works fine), here is a quick and sketchy addition you might consider alongside with 1. "Inline If with Logical && Operator" method and 2. using useState for checking if the api loading is over. With those three, mine worked.

Try fetching the desired data in the previous page of your app; in this case, add the following lines in any page you'll see before "SingleBeneficiary".

```
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8081/v1/beneficiary/${id}`);
    const jsonData = await response.json()
```

Maybe it has to do with npm cache, but not really sure what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
return (
 {data.title}
{data.address.careOf} 
)
```

with

```
return (
 {data?.title}
{data?.address?.careOf} 
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).